# How to rename a file if it already exists in directory (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen quite a few file uploads questions online, but it hasnt seemed to work for me.
I need to rename my file if it already exists in the directory.

I have even tried MSDN save as/rename method but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I'm missing something. I dont want to delete or override anything guys.

This is what I'm using so far, but it just overwrites the files

```
string folderName = Server.MapPath("\\Track\\Upload");    
string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, SupDDL.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
string fileName = QuoteUpload.FileName;
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
{
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pathString))
 {
   for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
   fs.WriteByte(i);
   }
QuoteUpload.SaveAs(pathString)}
}
```

Excuse me if I haven't given enough details, just let me know if you would like more information.

**UPDATED**

So I have updated it to this, it does the job, but I would like it to automatically increment numbers, instead of just adding the 2 once.

```
int count = 2;
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathString);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(pathString);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathString);
string newPath = pathString;

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
{
QuoteUpload.SaveAs(pathString);
}
else {
string tempName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
QuoteUpload.SaveAs(newPath); }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Why it doesn't works?

Comment: No error message, it just replaces the file already in the directory with the same name, overwrites it

Comment: Are you swallowing exceptions somewhere? Why doesn't your code crash because you keep the file open in the `fs` variable while calling `.SaveAs(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to just calling the save as.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
{
   QuoteUpload.SaveAs(pathString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this method and it is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is now "Rename()" method in c#.

It's not smart to run over 100 bytes, cause you'll never know how big is the upload file..

What you can do is create Help functions:

the first one - will check whether the file exists

the second one - will delete  / override the existing file

the third one - will upload the new file

as follows:
1 + 2.

```
public void DeleteFileIfExists(string BaseDir, string fileName)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(BaseDir);

    foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        string NameWithoutExtenstion = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
        if (NameWithoutExtenstion.Equals(fileName))
        {
            fi.Delete();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

3.

```
public void uploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase oldfile, string newFile, string Path, HttpServerUtilityBase Server)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Path),
                               Path.GetFileName(oldfile.FileName)); //file.FileName
    oldfile.SaveAs(path);
    System.IO.File.Copy(path, Server.MapPath(Path) + "/" + newName + ".FileExt");
    DeleteFileIfExists(Server.MapPath(Path), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldfile.FileName));
}
```

this following functions is good for any kind of files.

If you have any further question, please ask.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i dont want to delete or override the file

Answer (score 0):

There is no rename function, you can do this by copy file with new name and delete old one.

**C# Sample**

```
string strFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/FilesFolder/");
string strOldFileName = "OldFileName.rar";
string strNewFileName = "NewFilName.rar";

if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFilePath + strOldFileName)) {
    System.IO.FileInfo FileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilePath + strOldFileName);
    FileInfo.CopyTo(strFilePath + strNewFileName, true);
    FileInfo.Delete();
}
```

**VB Sample**

```
Dim strFilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/FilesFolder/")
Dim strOldFileName As String = "OldFileName.rar"
Dim strNewFileName As String = "NewFilName.rar"

If IO.File.Exists(strFilePath & strOldFileName) Then
    Dim FileInfo As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(strFilePath & strOldFileName)
    FileInfo.CopyTo(strFilePath & strNewFileName, True)
    FileInfo.Delete()
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I do not want to delete any files

Comment: It seems that question or title has been changed, In your case you only need to use "If IO.File.Exists(strFilePath & strFileName) Then" and if file exist, change the name in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Before the using you should put a check to rename the file if it exists:

```
            if (File.Exists(pathString))
                File.Move(pathString, newFilePath);
```